# Is it forbidden to lie down while a Quran recitation is heard?

Tags: halal-haram, quran

Is it forbidden (Haram) to lie down while a recitation of the Quran can be heard?

Comment: What do you mean 'playing the Qu'ran'? Do you mean she is listening to it on her phone etc?

Answer (score 2):

A similar question has been asked on [Islam QA](https://islamqa.info/en/124657) to which in response the below narration was cited showing that reciting the Quran is something you can do while lying down:

> Al-Bukhaari (7549) and Muslim (301) narrated that the Prophet (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to lie in ‘Aa’ishah’s lap
>   and recite Qur’aan

I don't see why this would be any different to when listening to it, this is confirmed by the below Narration:

> Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5960. It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may
>   Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) appointed me to guard the zakaah of
>   Ramadaan, and someone came and started to rummage in the food. I took
>   hold of him and said: “I am going to take you to the Messenger of
>   Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)”… And he said:
>   “When you go to your bed, recite Aayat al-Kursi, and you will have
>   ongoing protection from Allaah and no devil will come near you until
>   morning comes.” The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
>   him) said: “He spoke the truth even though he is a liar; that was a
>   devil.”